# Why the CURL PUT request with basic AUTH via API doesn't send JSON data?

Tags: php, json, curl, put

I make a **PHP CURL PUT JSON request with basic AUTH via API**:

```json
$data = <<<JSON
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "32",
    "address": {
                 "city": "London",
                 "street": "Laxin street 32",
                 "zip": "32567"
               }    
   } JSON;
```

Here is what I have:

```bash
$data_json = json_encode($data);
$url = "https://www.website.com/record?apiKey={API_KEY}";
$username = "user";
$password = "123abcd"; 
$encodedAuth = base64_encode($username.":".$password);
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authentication : Basic ".$encodedAuth),
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username.":".$password,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_json,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "TOKEN: SAMPLE_TOKEN"],]);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);    
        curl_close($curl);
```

In response, I got the **original record data** without changes that I sent via API.

How can I request that PUT using PHP's curl with basic auth? I tried some answers to similar questions but with no success.

Comment: What is the actual API hostname? What is the response status code?

Comment: quick questions why do you have 2 `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`? one is overwriting the other. Also why JSON like you posted and why not a php array and then `json_encode` it, there must be a problem with they way you are defining the JSON. Also if you are setting authentication header then why`CURLOPT_USERPWD ` and `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH `?

Comment: Hi Adi, Can you provide an example for "Also why JSON like you posted and why not a php array and then json_encode it, there must be a problem with they way you are defining the JSON"?

Comment: Ok, Adi, I sent JSON because I already have JSON and only need to add it additional data.

Comment: You are right I got back slashes: "\"{\\r\\n    \\\"name\\\": \\\"John\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"age\\\": \\\"32\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"address\\\": {\\r\\n                 \\\"city\\\": \\\"London\\\",\\r\\n                 \\\"street\\\": \\\"Laxin street 32\\\",\\r\\n                 \\\"zip\\\": \\\"32567\\\"\\r\\n               }    \\r\\n   } \""

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. Thank you.